# How can I check if the condition is true in terms of the last 10 candles/bars?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Could you please help me with the following?

I want the check the last 10 candles here and see if the condition is true in any cases.

```
for i = 1 to 10
    if (close > EMA5 and open > EMA5) or (close < EMA5 and open < EMA5))
        checkema5 == true
    else 
        checkema5 == false
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop. Write your condition and then use the `ta.barssince` function and check if it returns less than 10.

> Counts the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.

```
cond = (close > EMA5 and open > EMA5) or (close < EMA5 and open < EMA5)
bars_since_cond = ta.barssince(cond)
was_cond_true = (bars_since_cond < 10)
```